# Appending 0s to requirement numbers with decimals in Excel

Tags: excel

Basically I have a long list of IDs (over 900) formatted as follows (example):

1.1.1

etc

I'd want this to display as:

01.01.01

How do I add the 0s without messing up requirement numbers like 10.10.10 (I don't want this to display as 010.010.010 for example).

This may be a simple one hopefully! Basically just want to add a leading 0 when the number is less than 10.

Cheers

Comment: Do you have some more sample IDs and the desired outcome? Those where the numbers are bigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your List of IDs in Column A is as follows

```
1.1.1
2.2.2
1.3.1
1.2.3
1.10.1
1.1.10
10.1.1
10.1.10
10.10.10
1.10.10
```

Simple Excel solution would be to

1 - Select the range in Column A. Go to `Data --> Text to Columns --> Delimited --> Other -->  Put . as delim text`. This will divide your Column A data into 3 Columns as shown below

[image]

2 - In D1, enter `=TEXT(A1,"00")`. Drag and fill D1:F10
[image]

3 - Enter `.` in G1 and then drag and fill till G10

4 - In H1, enter `=CONCATENATE(D1,G1,E1,G1,F1)` and drag and fill till H10 and voilà !

[image]

VBA solution would be

```
Sub vbaSol()
    For Each dataCell In Range("A1:A10")
        splitData = Split(dataCell.Value, ".")
        For i = 0 To UBound(splitData)
            If CInt(splitData(i)) < 10 Then splitData(i) = "0" & CStr(splitData(i))
        Next i
        dataCell.Value = Join(splitData, ".")
    Next dataCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Tackle it in 3 parts, and then concatenate the answer.  For the left third, use the FIND() function to locate the first dot/period inside the LEFT() function inside the TEXT() function as so:  TEXT(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1),"00.")  This will give you 01.->10.

For the right third, use the FIND() function with its optional 3rd argument to specify where to start looking for the dot.  The 2nd dot can be no earlier than the 4th character. Subtract the FIND() from the length LEN() function, inside the RIGHT() function inside the TEXT() function as so: TEXT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1,4)),"00") This gives you 01->10.

For the middle third, use the MID() function with a combination of FIND() functions to get your numbers.  It's more complicated, but looks like this:
TEXT(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)-FIND(".",A1)),"00.")
Get the middle of A1 from 1 character past the first dot to a length of "find the second dot minus find the first dot."  Turn it into text.

All together, looks like this:
=TEXT(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1),"00.")&TEXT(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)-FIND(".",A1)),"00.")&TEXT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1,4)),"00")